# Javafx Combobox update issue when updating the observable values

Tags: javafx-8

I have create a `ComboBox` in `JavaFx` as in the following image

[image]

Then i have selected a particular value which shows up in the button cell as shown in the figure.

[image]

Then i updated its value so if there is a change in the value i can observe it. But it is not displaying the changed value but an object value.

[image]

When i again select from the dropdown view the selected value becomes correct.

[image]

The code for the `Combobox` is

```
    ComboBox<AspectRatio> aspectRatio = new ComboBox<>();
    aspectRatio.setCellFactory(new AspectRatioCellFactory());
    aspectRatio.setButtonCell(new AspectRatioCell());
```

Cell Factory

```
class AspectRatioCellFactory implements Callback<ListView<AspectRatio>, ListCell<AspectRatio>> {
@Override
public ListCell<AspectRatio> call(ListView<AspectRatio> param) {
    return new AspectRatioCell();
}
}

class AspectRatioCell extends ListCell<AspectRatio> {
public AspectRatioCell() {
    super();
}

@Override
protected void updateItem(AspectRatio item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (item == null || empty) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        setText(item.getAspectRatio());
        setGraphic(null);
    }
}
}
```

Updating class

```
private class RefreshButtonListener implements ButtonListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        theModel.setObservableAspectRatios(theModel.getAllAspectRatio());
        theView.clearCombo();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create a [StringConverter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/StringConverter.html) and assign it to the [converter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#converterProperty) property of the `ComboBox`. Since I didn't find code for class `AspectRatio`, in your question, I can't help you with writing the `StringConverter`. You can [edit] your question and add that code, if you like. Alternatively, just override method `toString` in class `AspectRatio`, since the default `StringConverter` calls that method.

Comment: Thanks i have override toString and its working